# SQL row into string format (stringify as file-reading format)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

The thing is to read data from a database, but string it like `.txt` format. (`SELECT *` into one string, each field separated by ;)

Let's say one file (`.txt`) from the an FTP server is:

```
Christopher;Nolan;1970
```

And also this data exists in the database as a row separated in columns like:

```
First_Name, Second_Name, Birth_Date: Christopher, Nolan, 1970
```

Can I format the data gotten from the `SELECT` to look like the `.txt` mentioned above using JavaScript (Node.js)? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when data is returned from a database it is in an array. Therefor you could do the following.

Javascript

const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log ( fruits.join(';') );

Output
Banana;Orange;Apple;Mango

If you wanted to do this at the database level you could also run the following  (depending on the database you are using)

SELECT CONCAT(col1, ';'. col2, ';', col3) AS ConcatenatedString;

Comment: Thank you a lot, it was useful not only for the question's purpose but also in understanding how the data is returned.